# PHP sleep forces slow queries

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sleep

im experiencing a problem where i have

one insert 
then sleep(25) 
then second insert.

datetime from first insert ALWAYS matches the datetime from second insert.

The problem is that both inserts happen at the same time after sleep. So i placed a condition for the second insert that checks for the first insert but the problem is there. I am using Zend DB select.

Notes:
I have also tried live()->query($sql) and have the same results

```
            $sql = "insert into leads_verify
            (customer, lead_id,dt)
            values
            ('2'
            ,'111'
            ,'". date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";

            $queryResult = Db::live()->exec($sql);

            if($queryResult <> '5' ){
                sleep(24);
            }

            $sql2 = "insert into leads_verify
            (customer, lead_id,dt)
            values
            ('3'
            ,'222'
            ,'". date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')";

                          $queryResult = Db::live()->exec($sql2);
```

The datetime of insertion is always the same for both. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `$queryResult <> '5'`? Try `$queryResult !== 5` instead. Assumed that the query result is an integer

Comment: A guess of mine is that the queries are not committed until the script exits or some other time later on.

Comment: are you sure that the if condition matches? what if you comment it out?

Comment: var_dump($queryResult) and check it's value.

Comment: @321x queryresults is always 1, i tested the !==5 and the problem occured.

ExplosionPills - i think you are right, how can i force the query to execute?

RomanKonz -the condition was put there on purpose to see if i can somehow force the first query. 

any ideas?

Comment: @val try `commit` after the first query.

Comment: are you sure, your sleep() is not interrupted by any signal? did you check if the 24 s are really slept? how long does the script load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i used was to connect using mysql_query and run the sql that way. Thanks aLL

Comment: there was a transaction wrapper, which i removed and split into two transactions

Answer (score 1):

Are you using transactions in Zend?

then you need to commit your statements:

```
Db::live()->commit();
```

and by the way:
if the `dt` field is of the type `DATE` ore `DATETIME`, you can use `Now()` instead of `'". date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'`

Comment: I thought about the commit/atomicity part, but if between a query and another there's 25 seconds' difference, and since he's using `date()`, rather than the SQL equivalent, I don't think commit would be the issue.

Comment: I am not creating a transaction when i do these inserts. Not that i am aware of. I have added the commit to see how it works though

IT WORKS!!!! also thanks for the now suggestion! :) you the man +1

Comment: It didnt work, i didnt notice the error that said there was no transaction to commit.

Comment: and what are the timestamps, if you use `NOW()`?

Comment: I changed to NOW() and the timestamps were identical. It must be overall transaction or something in the framework